# nodejs express loads .css file correctly in localhost but fail at live plesk webserver

Tags: css, node.js, express, plesk-onyx

**The Problem**

I have a simple Nodejs Express *Hello_World* application up and running both locally and on a live server using *Plesk-Onyx17.8.11*. The app runs correctly on `localhost:3000` in my browser:

[image: working express app in localhost]

But after I push the files to the server (using a Filezilla ftp client), my browser can't load the files in the public folder, so it won't load the CSS file:

[image: not loading CSS on server]

As you can see the file `http://shamimkeshani.ir/stylesheets/style.css` cannot be downloaded. This is the correct URL, because we use `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));` in the Express app. But hypothetically if we insert a *wrong* URL file of `http://shamimkeshani.ir/public/stylesheets/style.css` it would find the file and download it correctly from `shamimkeshani.ir`, which is not the correct behavior! Also, this will not work locally which is the right behavior!!

[image]

[image]

**The codes**

I used `express-generator` to create the default *Hello_World* Express application. The `app.js` file:

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./routes/users');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
console.log(__dirname);
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);
app.use('/users', usersRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

I use a `server.js` file to run the Nodejs application. This file is actually a copy of `./bin/www` file that Express uses. I use `npm start` which runs this file locally. Also, the `server.js` file is set in the Plesk for starting the application on the server:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/**
 * Module dependencies.
 */

var app = require('./app');
var debug = require('debug')('app:server');
var http = require('http');

/**
 * Get port from environment and store in Express.
 */

var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);

/**
 * Create HTTP server.
 */

var server = http.createServer(app);

/**
 * Listen on provided port, on all network interfaces.
 */

server.listen(port);
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);

/**
 * Normalize a port into a number, string, or false.
 */

function normalizePort(val) {
  var port = parseInt(val, 10);

  if (isNaN(port)) {
    // named pipe
    return val;
  }

  if (port >= 0) {
    // port number
    return port;
  }

  return false;
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "error" event.
 */

function onError(error) {
  if (error.syscall !== 'listen') {
    throw error;
  }

  var bind = typeof port === 'string'
    ? 'Pipe ' + port
    : 'Port ' + port;

  // handle specific listen errors with friendly messages
  switch (error.code) {
    case 'EACCES':
      console.error(bind + ' requires elevated privileges');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    case 'EADDRINUSE':
      console.error(bind + ' is already in use');
      process.exit(1);
      break;
    default:
      throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Event listener for HTTP server "listening" event.
 */

function onListening() {
  var addr = server.address();
  var bind = typeof addr === 'string'
    ? 'pipe ' + addr
    : 'port ' + addr.port;
  debug('Listening on ' + bind);
}
```

`package.json` file:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11"
  }
}
```

I also checked the Nodejs versions running locally and at the server and they both match (10.1.0).

I searched a lot and couldn't figure out how to solve this problem. I want for my Nodejs application to work the same locally and on the server. Any additional thoughts on the future problems that I may encounter and any further suggestions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: On first look, it seems like `plesk` might not be using your node server instead it's using it's own server to run your application.

Comment: This may sounds silly, try to remove `/` from public like this `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));`. i had a similar issue.

Comment: @dimitristseggenes did it, same story!